# react native - how to get form data when pressing on navigation bar submit button from a different view (class)

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I am new to React Native, so I might have missed on some tricks on how to do things properly. Sorry if the question in the title is a bit vague. Let me instead explain using an example:

I have a file called **root.js** that navigates (using navigator) to a new view called **signupform.js** which contains a 'submit' button on the navigation bar. Note that the navigation bar is created on **root.js** and is independent of **signupform.js**

(I want to know how to do this)
Say, when a user finishes filling up all the fields in the sign up form, they can click on the 'submit' button from the navigation bar, which should trigger say a navigator.push that contains a passed props of the form data to a view say **processdata.js**. However, I don't know how to get the data passed to the **processdata.js** view since the navigation bar 'submit' button is not part of the **signupform.js** view.

(I can do this. But I prefer scenario above) One simple solution is to have a 'submit' button in the same view as **signupform.js** instead of being part of the navigation bar. That way when the user click on the 'submit' button from the same view, I can easily take the data and do a navigator.push().

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if my example is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is very elegant, but one way of doing it would be, to keep a 'isSaving' value in the state of root. This value is handed as a prop to the signup form.

In the form you implement

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    if(nextPorps.isSaving && ! this.props.isSaving) {
        ... do something ...
    }
}
```

The *something* to do depends a lot on your architecture. Here are three options:

1. You do your HTTP call directly in form. In that case you need to pass in a callback to root in order to update the state there once the network call returns.
2. You handle the HTTP call in root. In that case you need to hand in a callback to root that receives the form data.
3. If you use some kind of Flux-like implementation you trigger an action with the form data

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give that a try :)